# Mapping using Custom XSLT for multiple occurrence of the source

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a Source XML as follows---

```
<Characteristics>
    <Cname>.....</Cname>
    <Cvalue>....</Cvalue>
</Characteristics>
```

Now the above element 'Characteristics' may have multiple occurrences.

Then we have the target XML as follows

```
<Parent>
  <elem_a/>
  <elem_b/>
  <elem_c/>
  <elem_d/>
     .
     .
     .
</Parent>
```

Now the requirement is, for every occurrence of 'Characteristics', we first check, the value of the sub-element 'Cname'; it is given that, the value of the element 'Cname' will always be 'elem_a' or 'elem_b' or 'elem_c' so on... and they can appear in any order as follows---

```
<Characteristics>
    <Cname>elem_d</Cname>
    <Cvalue>123</Cvalue>
</Characteristics>
<Characteristics>
    <Cname>elem_a</Cname>
    <Cvalue>073</Cvalue>
</Characteristics>
       .
       .
       .
```

So, when the value of the element 'Cname' is 'elem_a', then we will send the value of the element 'Cvalue' to the target element 'elem_a'

I tried to go forward as follows, but then I'm stuck.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Characteristics/node()[contains(local-name(),&apos;Cname&apos;)]">
<xsl:if test="contains(./text(),'elem_a')>
<Parent xmlns=" ">
    <elem_a xmlns=" ">
        <xsl:value-of select="Characteristics/Cvalue/text()"/>
    </elem_a>
</Parent>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

After writing above piece of code, I realize that I cannot dynamically check and map the values at a time.

SO, it will be helpful, if anyone say the approach how can I dynamically check and send the values correctly at a time

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that your input XML should be well-formed, which means it must have single root element that contains all your `Characteristics` elements. Something like this:

```
<parent>
    <Characteristics>
        <Cname>elem_d</Cname>
        <Cvalue>123</Cvalue>
    </Characteristics>
    <Characteristics>
        <Cname>elem_a</Cname>
        <Cvalue>073</Cvalue>
    </Characteristics>
</parent>
```

But to answer your question, you can use the `xsl:element` element here, which (together with an Attribute Value Template) allows you to specify an element dynamically. So, you would write something like this

```
 <xsl:element name="{Cname}">
```

Note the use of curly braces, which means it is treated as an expression to be evaluated to get the name. (i.e The name of the element will be whatever the value of the `Cname` element is in your XML) If you just wrote `<xsl:element name="Cname" />` it would literally create an element `<cname>`

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="Characteristics">
      <xsl:element name="{Cname}">
          <xsl:value-of select="Cvalue" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <parent>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </parent>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: If you want the resultant elements ordered, you can use an `xsl:sort` instruction with the `xsl:apply-templates`. Try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="Characteristics">
      <xsl:element name="{Cname}">
          <xsl:value-of select="Cvalue" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <parent>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Characteristics">
                <xsl:sort select="Cname" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </parent>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT 2: If the "target XML" is an actual file that you effectively want to populate with the `Characteristics` data, another approach to take to use the `document` function to access the target XML in the XSLT, and simply iterate over the child nodes, populating them with data from the source XML.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:variable name="Characteristics" select="//Characteristics" />

    <xsl:template match="Parent/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="$Characteristics[Cname = local-name(current())]/Cvalue" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Parent>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('Target.xml')/Parent/*" />
        </Parent>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: but i think there would be a problem... if in the occurrences the value of the 'Cname' elements are in order like elem_c, elem_b, elem_a,... then the elements will be created also in the same order & the corresponding values will also be selected in the same order. but then if the elements of the target under 'Parent' is in order 'elem_a', 'elem_b', 'elem_c', ... then this order will not be maintained.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to show how you can order the results.

Comment: for the sake of simplicity I've written the names of the sub-elements of the 'Parent' (target) tag as 'elem_a', 'elem_f', 'elem_b', 'elem_e', 'elem_c', ..... like this, but those local-name of the elements might be anything and then as a result we just can't simply apply 'sort'

Comment: I've made another edit to my answer, assuming that the "Target XML" is an actual file which contains the order you want.